# textarea correct size when in focus but gets about 5px bigger when not

Tags: html, css

I ran into an issue when making identically sized `<textarea>` and `<p>` side by side.

All is well when textarea is in focus, but as soon as unfocus, the textarea gets about 3px larger for no reason.

Anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

code:

```
<textarea id="keyInput" rows="1" inputType="text" onInput="keyFun()" autofocus></textarea>
```

and

```
#keyInput {
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 1.5;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;

    width: 350px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 7px solid white;
}
```

Any and all help to make the `textarea` size stable on focus and unfocus is greatly appreciated.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/borderstep/pen/KorQaM)

Comment: The CodePen link you shared seems to work fine for me, are you able to post a sample that behaves as you describe? Also, what browser(s) have you tested on? Are there any CSS frameworks in use?

Comment: Hello @Ian . I tested in Chrome only, and use no CSS frameworks. Hmm.. you're right - in terms of border, it seems to behave as expected on mozilla, but the font is some pizels off... Uhh.

Answer (score 1):

if you remove

```
outline: 7px solid white;
```

It won't grow-and-shrink.

You can also set the background color to the same as html and so the effect is not obvious like so: `outline: 7px solid #DFCFBE`

Comment: You're right. However, I need it for enlarging the textarea by 7px. Any alternative?
Just border-width doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Okay.. If I do that, how can I make the textarea background larger by a margin of 7px ?

Comment: add `margin-left: 7px;` on your `#showKey` might give the effect you are looking for?

Comment: Hello TLJ... Thanks for your help. But the margin nor padding solve the issue..
The issue i'm struggling is probaly due to th edifferences in webkit betwee browsers... It looks how it's supposed to in mozilla, (kind of) but the border jumps in chrome... I think there's no solution..